# Android bundle testing release

Tags: android, bundle, release

I'm trying to create an **internal testing release** for my Android app inside the Google Play Console, but when I hit "Review release" I get these 2 errors:

1. Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_NO_APKS
2. This release does not add or remove any APKs or App Bundles.

And it doesn't generate the release. I couldn't find anything online that could explain why this.

PLEASE HELP !

Comment: Any luck on your issue?

Comment: Honestly no. I just checked all resources and then I succeded. Maybe the problem could be related to strings not transaleted to the main language of the app... but it is just an idea...